# How do I add the support libraries to an AOSP build so they become part of the system image?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-source

I am creating a system app where I have to request specific permissions from the user at runtime. This requires me to use classes ContextCompat and ActivityCompat which are from the support library.

Example:

`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission`(...)         `ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale`(...)
    `ActivityCompat.requestPermission`

When I run make, I get the errors:

***The import android.support cannot be resolved"***

***"ContextCompat cannot be resolved"***

***"The method shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(String) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments(DownloadUtil, String[], int)"***

***"The method requestPermissions(String[], int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments(DownloadUtil, String[], int)"***

NOTE: DownloadUtil is my Activity

I'd like to know how to include the support libraries in the build to eliminate these errors

Comment: "This requires me to use classes ContextCompat and ActivityCompat which are from the support library" -- no, it does not. You are welcome to call the equivalent methods on `Context` and `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I did call the equivalent methods on `Context` and `Activity` and the errors were resolved. I still need to add support libraries as part of the system image.

Comment: At most, you need to add them to your app. Since those libraries are Java code, presumably you add them the same way that you add any other Java code. If, OTOH, you are proposing to add these libraries to the zygote, that is stupid beyond words, if this device will be running any apps other than ones that you wrote. [Leave your hands off the zygote](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/12/11/manufacturers-keep-your-hands-off-my-zygote.html), please.